# How do I print the second highest number from input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, max

I can only use `>, <` not `min` and `max` functions. The code is supposed to ask for value until the value is a negative number. I know that the first number that comes in is both the largest and the second largest.
Number 2 can then:

- be greater than number 1 and then number 2 is the largest and number 1 is the next largest.
- be smaller than number 1 and then number 2 is next largest and take 1 largest.

Then comes number 3:

- if it is bigger than 1 and 2, number 3 is the biggest
- if it is smaller than the largest, say number 1 and larger than the next largest, say number 2, then number 3 becomes the next largest and number 1 the largest
- if it is smaller than both, then the largest and the next largest are the same.

How can I use that?
My code:

```
seclarg = 0
large = 0
while n >= 0 :

    n = int(input("Value: "))
    if n > large :
        large = n

    if n > seclarg :
        seclarg = n

print(f"Largest: {large}")
print(f"Second largest: {seclarg}")
```

What I expect to happen is this:

```
Value: 5 
Value: 5 
Value: -1 
Largest: 5 
Second largest: 5
```

Comment: Did you try to debug this yourself? Using some `print`s or a debugger or [pythontutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) might help. Think about your logic: if the new `n` is indeed the largest, what do you think that implies about the condition ` if n > seclarg :`?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have now. But an error appears.

```
large = 0
seclarg = 0

while n > 0 :
    n = int(input("Value: "))
    if n >= large :
        large = n
    elif n >= seclarg :
        seclarg = n
print(f"Largest: {large}")
print(f"Second largest: {seclarg}")
```

Comment: I was going to ask about your error. Can you update your question with your current code and the full error traceback?